# German equivalent of "since before"

Tags: english-to-german

What would be the German equivalent of "since before" as in "I have lived here since before 1990"?

Comment: You could say *Ich lebe hier seit vor 1990* but this would by rather colloquial. No good way to express yourself in written communication.

Comment: Would it still be authentic German?

Comment: In colloquial speach - and a situation where this is appropriate - you can say this and nobody would suspect that German is not your first language. However, a better way (less colloquial) to say it would be e.g. *Ich lebe hier schon seit der Zeit vor 1990.* This, you could say in a more formal setting. Anyway the reference to 1990 is a little bit strange. You need a specific reason to mention 1990, say, the political changes in Eastern Europe or so. When 1990 plays a specific role, this sentence could make sense.

Comment: PS: Perhaps in a dialogue like this: *A: "Ich lebe hier seit 1990." B: "Ich lebe hier schon seit vor 1990."* - Or in more normal wording: *B: "Ich lebe hier schon länger als seit 1990."*

Comment: Did you try online translaters, to find the answer yourself? Why were they of no help?

Comment: Because "online translators" don't give answers to "specific questions of general interest". My question is a specific question of general interest, which is obvious from Christian Geiselmann's and tofro's answers.

Answer (score 2):

German expresses the "long time" by *particles*, something English needs to live without. Your example sentence would translate to something like

> Ich lebe hier schon seit [vor|mindestens] 1990.

"schon" expresses a sort of "astonishment" ("really that long?) that English transports with "since before".

Comment: Does "since before" transport an astonishment?